# Is there a way to change the style basedon property programmatically?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I have the below code which is basically the default tabbed view with an added style that sets back color to green instead of the dynamic primary.

```
 <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element" >
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="GreenStyle" TargetType="Element" >
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="Green" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="Green" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>
```

I want to know if it is possible to change the TabBar BasedOn property programmatically to the GreenStyle. Such as:

```
*Trigger*
{
TabBar.BasedOn = GreenStyle;
}
```

But in a way that actually works.

I am asking because it does not seem to work dynamically due to the static nature of it and it will not let me change it to a:

```
<Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{DynamicResource BaseStyle}" />
```

Any workarounds accepted so long as I can change the color/style to green from whatever color it is set to and back. I am very new to Xamarin forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to change the style basedon property programmatically?

For this, you can use `Dynamic Styles` to achieve this function.
Applications can respond to style changes dynamically at runtime by using dynamic resources.

You can refer the following code:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="baseStyle" TargetType="View">
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="blueSearchBarStyle" TargetType="SearchBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}">
            <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Italic" />
            <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="Blue" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="greenSearchBarStyle" TargetType="SearchBar">
            <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="None" />
            <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Large" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="0,20,0,0">
        <SearchBar Placeholder="These SearchBar controls" Style="{DynamicResource searchBarStyle}" />
        <SearchBar Placeholder="are demonstrating" Style="{DynamicResource searchBarStyle}" />
        <SearchBar Placeholder="dynamic styles," Style="{DynamicResource searchBarStyle}" />
        <SearchBar Placeholder="but this isn't dynamic" Style="{StaticResource blueSearchBarStyle}" />
        <Button Text="Change Style" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The `xaml.cs` code is :

```
public partial class DynamicStylesPage : ContentPage
{
    bool originalStyle = true;

    public DynamicStylesPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        Resources ["searchBarStyle"] = Resources ["blueSearchBarStyle"];
    }

    void OnButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (originalStyle) {
            Resources ["searchBarStyle"] = Resources ["greenSearchBarStyle"];
            originalStyle = false;
        } else {
            Resources ["searchBarStyle"] = Resources ["blueSearchBarStyle"];
            originalStyle = true;
        }
    }
}
```

For more details,please check document [Dynamic Styles in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/dynamic).

And there is a sample included in above ducument, you can check it here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-styles-dynamicstyles/